# How to update and refresh in PyQt5 at a higher frequency

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, refresh

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    signal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.buttonList = list()
        self.counter = 0
        self.setUI()
        self.signal.connect(self.updatebutton)
        self.startTimer(10)
    def timerEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.signal.emit()

    def updatebutton(self):
        for button in self.buttonList:  # type: QLabel or QPushButton
            button.setText(str(self.counter))
        self.counter += 1

    def setUI(self):
        gridLayout = QGridLayout()
        for i in range(10):
            for j in range(10):
                button = QLabel(self)#QPushButton(self)
                self.buttonList.append(button)
                gridLayout.addWidget(button, i, j)
        self.setLayout(gridLayout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

1. When I set the timer at 10 ms, all Labels can increase its value by 100 per second. However, when I change the timer to 1 ms, all Labels can not increase its value by 1000 per second.
2. When I use Pushbutton instead of Label, even the timer is set to 100 ms, all buttons can not increase their value by 100 per second. But when I reduce the number of buttons, e.g., totally 10 buttons instead of 100, these buttons can work well.
   3.I meet with this problem recently when I used a data acquisition software called DEWESOFT, which can produce many subwidget or subwindow(very similar to QMidArea and QMidSubwindow) to draw curves and display values of high-frequency signals. Hence, I'd like to find out how and why. I wonder how to control the refresh rate of widget and how to determine the limit of UI refresh ability. If I wanna refresh more widgets at a high frequency, what should I do?
3. Later I tried Thread to improve, it seems to work a litter better, but I don't know why.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import threading
import sys
import time


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    signal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.buttonList = list()
        self.counter = 0
        self.setUI()
        self.signal.connect(self.updatebutton)

        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.timerevent, args=())
        self.thread.setDaemon(True)
        self.thread.start()

        # self.startTimer(10)

    def timerEvent(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.signal.emit()

    def timerevent(self):
        while True:
            self.signal.emit()
            time.sleep(0.01)

    def updatebutton(self):
        print(self.counter)
        for button in self.buttonList:  # type: QPushButton
            button.setText(str(self.counter))
        self.counter += 1

    def setUI(self):
        gridLayout = QGridLayout()
        for i in range(10):
            for j in range(10):
                button = QPushButton(self)
                self.buttonList.append(button)
                gridLayout.addWidget(button, i, j)
        self.setLayout(gridLayout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It's very unlikely that you'll be able to manage a 1ms update, and, even in that case, you wouldn't see the result: even the most modern computers have a refresh rate lower than 150Hz, meaning that you'd only see updates every 6-7ms, but in most cases you'd only get refresh of 15-16ms tops. In any case, I believe you might be looking for the wrong answer (meaning that it's likely that you actually have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you *really* trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind help. I try to make myself clear. What I am really confused about is the number of widgets to refresh at the same time. As I stated in my question, when I used 10 buttons in a layout, all button can increase their value by 100 per second if I set the Timer to 10 ms. But when I increase the number of buttons to 100 in a the layout, all buttons can not increase their value by 100 per second (typically only 50 or 60) even if I set the timer to 10 ms.

Comment: You've to consider that updating the text of a button is not as simple as it might seem. Buttons calculate the possible size based on their contents (text, possible icon, margins and spacings), and then each button notifies the layout that contains it using those size. The text size is computed on a *variable* size based on the font (simply speaking: uppercase "L" has a different width than a lowercase "l"), you've to multiply that computed time by the amount of widgets shown and also consider that the whole layout has to, eventually, update its parent widget based on the *sum* of those sizes.

Comment: Thanks again for your valuable advice. Maybe I need to do some tests to find out the truth.